# Abréviation de « mise en scène »

Tags: abréviations, spectacle

Selon [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mise_%C3%A0_jour) (je n'ai pas cherché plus loin), l'expression « mise à jour » est abrégée « MAJ » ou « MàJ ».

Quelle serait l'abréviation **correcte** de « mise en scène » ou de « metteur en scène » ? J'ai beau chercher sur Google, je n'ai rien trouvé de concluant. Références, s'il vous plaît.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce qui **serait l'abbréviation correcte** dans le cas où les circonstances justifieraient une telle abbréviation — puisque c'est comme ça que je comprends la question — serait **m. e. sc.**, éventuellement *m. en sc.*, en différenciant probablement d'avec **mett. en sc.**
D'après l'[*Orthotypographie*](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-I/abreviations-01.html#3-2) de Jean-Pierre Lacroux, qui en cite bien d'autres.

Maintenant, je ne vois ça se justifier que dans des textes très spécialisés…

Comment: Merci! La référence est en plus inestimable!

Answer (score 8):

On trouve de très rares références à *ms*, *mes* ou *mett. scène* sur le net, mais ce sont plus des inventions que des abréviations globalement acceptées.

Je serais de l'avis de dire que *mise en scène* ou *metteur en scène* n'ont tout simplement pas d'abréviation établie.